# array en insert php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

tengo el siguiente problema estoy trabajando con php y codeigniter, y necesito hacer la siguiente insert en mi modelo este es mi codigo:

```html
public function guardar_permisos(){
    
    $perfil = $this->session->userdata("perfil");
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($this->input->post("data")));
    
    foreach ($data as $idpagina) {
      $this->db->set('Id_perfil', $perfil);
      $this->db->set('Id_pagina', $idpagina);
      $sql = $this->db->insert('perfil_pagina');
    }
           if($sql === true) {
           return true; 
        }else {
       return false;
      }

  }
```

esta mi funcion para insertar los datos, en la variable perfil capturo el id del perfil que tiene el usuario de la session, y el la variable data mediante post tengo un array y necesito insertar por cada valor del array una fila. por ejemplo si tengo 
en las variables los siguientes datos:

- $perfil = 1
- $data = [2,3,5]

realizar un insert por cada uno

- insert into perfil_pagina (Id_perfil,Id_pagina) values (1,2)
- insert into perfil_pagina (Id_perfil,Id_pagina) values (1,3)
- insert into perfil_pagina (Id_perfil,Id_pagina) values (1,5)

espero se entienda y me den una pauta de como realizar esto en codeigniter

```html
<form id="formid">
<label>V<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check" class="up"><span class="lever"></span></label>
<label>G<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check" class="up"><span class="lever"></span></label>
<label>M<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check" class="up"><span class="lever"></span></label>
<label>E<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="check" class="up"><span class="lever"></span></label>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn bg-blue">Guardar</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#send').click(function(){
           var select = [];
           $(":checkbox[name=check]").each(function() {
             if (this.checked) {
               select.push($(this).val());
              }
            });
           if (select.length) {
             var jsonString = JSON.stringify(select);
             $.ajax({
               cache: false,
               type: 'post',  
               data: {data : jsonString},  
               url: '<?php echo site_url();?>user/guardar',
               success: function(data) {
                }
              });
            }else
           alert('seleccione');     
           return false;
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso lo podrías hacer en el controlador, en el modelo solo deja la función para guardar. Por ejemplo la función en tu modelo podría quedar asi:

```
public function guardar_permisos($arreglo){
    if($this->db->insert('perfil_pagina',$arreglo)){
      return true;
    }else{
      return $this->db->error();
    }
}
```

Y en tu controlador podrías hacer algo asi:

```
public function guardar(){
    $perfil = $this->session->userdata("perfil");
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($this->input->post("data")));

    //suponiendo que data es un arreglo del tipo $data = [2,3,5]
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
      $arreglo = ["Id_perfil"=>$perfil, "Id_pagina" => $value];

      //mi_modelo cambialo por el nombre de tu modelo
      if($this->mi_modelo->guardar_permisos($arreglo)){
        echo "Agregado";
      }else{
        echo "Error";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias.. :) estoy mandando mis datos en json? crees q esta bien de esa forma

Comment: Los envias a traves de ajax, o como los estás enviando en json?

Comment: si por ajax, es un grupo de check de un formulario, que lo paso a mi controlador. paso el codigo de mi script a mi pregunta.

Comment: Si, coloca la llamada ajax

Comment: ya puse el codigo en mi pregunta

Comment: Coloca tambien el formulario que tienes, para ver como tienes los checkbox

Comment: claro, ya agrege eso tambien a la pregunta

Comment: Ok, ya lo revise, el script en tu controlador no debería tener ningún problema, ejecutalo y mira si obtienes algun error

Comment: ya lo probe nuevamente, y si me guarda pero solo cuando tengo un check, cuando selecciono mas de uno no los guarda, solo el primero